# usb flash drive read only on one partition

Tags: usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, read-only

So I've got problem, what I want is precisely 2 partition on one USB-flash drive with 8GB - 16GB size, which is:

1. The first partition is only 1GB, contain the company portfolio, on that partition it will un-write-able disk and you cant delete that partition.
2. The another partition is the rest of the space that you can use as normal USB-drives.

I want to used it on windows 10 since on the update 1709 it can read more than 1 USB-drives partition
I want to make the first partition as ads for the company, and the second partition as usual USB-drive and i want the USB-drive **unformatable** so the file on first partition won't disappear

I already tried on using `diskpart` command to do read-only but both partition cant do write, also it still formatable

is it possible? how can I do it? or is there any alternative to my case?

Comment: There are custom flash drives you can purchase for exactly this purpose, that internally lock the partition.  But there is no way to do this with an off-the-shelf unit.

Comment: can you give me the link for the seller of this kind of USB?

Comment: Unfortunately, don't know a specific supplier to recommend.